# Counter example for $f( \cap_{E \in \epsilon} E) \supseteq \cap_{E \in \epsilon} f(E)$

Tags: functions

I'm having difficulty wrapping my head around the idea of a collection of subsets. I'm trying to think of a counter example for  $f( \cap_{E \in \epsilon} E) \supseteq  \cap_{E \in \epsilon}  f(E)$ where $\epsilon$ is a collection of subsets in X and $E \subset X$.

Comment: Consider thecase in which the family has exactly two sets. You can even find an example in which the domain of $f$ has two elements and the codomain exactly one...

Comment: Let me try it out. Say $f(x)=x^2$. Then let $\epsilon$={4, 9}. Then on the LHS we have f({4,9})={16,81) while on the RHS we have {4,9}?

Comment: Can you find a function $f:X\to Y$ and two subsets $A$ and $B$ of $X$ such that $f(A\cap B)\not\supseteq f(A)\cap f(B)$? If you do, then $\mathcal E=\{A,B\}$ is a collection of sets which does what you want.

Comment: A collection $\mathcal E$ of sets is simply a set of sets and in your attempt at an example has $\mathcal E$ not such a thing.

Comment: Hmm. I keep thinking of examples where $f(A \cap B) \supseteq f(A) \cap f(B)$. I'll keep working on it. Thanks!

Comment: read my first comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use the function $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ defined by $f(x) = x^2$ and choose the sets $E_1 = (-\infty,0]$ and $E_2 = [0,\infty)$ with $\mathcal E = \{E_1,E_2\}$. Then

$$f\left(\bigcap_{E \in \mathcal E} E\right) = f(E_1 \cap E_2) = f\bigl((-\infty,0] \cap [0,\infty)\bigr)= f(\{0\}) = \{0\}$$

but

$$\bigcap_{E \in \mathcal E} f(E) = f(E_1) \cap f(E_2) = f\bigl((-\infty,0]\bigr) \cap f\bigl([0,\infty)\bigr) = [0,\infty) \cap [0,\infty) = [0,\infty).$$

---

Note that if you used $(-\infty,0)$ and $(0,\infty)$, then your intersection for the left would actually be empty!

Also, you can find counterexamples for any function that is not one-to-one since if $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$, but $x_1 \ne x_2$, then $E_1 = \{x_1\}$ and $E_2 = \{x_2\}$. Thus $f(E_1 \cap E_2) = f(\varnothing) = \varnothing$, but $f(E_1) \cap f(E_2) = f(x_1) = f(x_2) \not\subseteq \varnothing$

Comment: Oh thank you so much! I see. A collection of sets is just literally a collection of sets. Don't know why I struggled so much. Thank you!!